# Is there a way to use GIT to manage OS packages so that if i 'sudo' break something I can easily revert?

Tags: apt, package-management, git

I'm very novice when it comes to OS management, so if this question is ignorant please be kind.

The idea is pretty self explanatory, essentially keep a text file of packages&versions, every change creates a new git commit. If something breaks, you can revert to a previously set up and apt handles the removing/installing/versioning of packages to match that previous environment.

If this does not exist, I would appreciate any advice / links to advice on proper OS management.
Thank you!

Comment: You can use git to keep configuration files under version control (see [`etckeeper`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html)). The proper way would be to use filesystem-level snapshots, or use LVM snapshots. That way, you restore the whole OS.

Comment: No; `git` is not a backup system.  Use `tar` or `dump` for that.

Comment: I understand the point of backing up your system, but `sudo` should be used sparingly, and almost _always_ run a command as a regular user before running it as root. I've personally never broken my system with `sudo` by using it sparingly and knowing where and where not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There's some tools that can do the job using snapshots (not like version control systems):

## [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback):

> Simple system backup and restore application with extra features
>
> Systemback makes it easy to create backups of system and users
>   configuration files. In case of problems you can easily restore the
>   previous state of the system. There are extra features like system
>   copying, system installation and Live system creation.
>
> Installation:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install systemback
> ```

## [BackInTime](http://backintime.le-web.org/documentation/):

> Back In Time acts as a “user mode” backup system. This means that you
>   can backup/restore only folders you have write access to (actually you
>   can backup read-only folders, but you can’t restore them).
>
> If you want to run it as root you need to use “su” (command line),
>   “gksu” (Gnome) or “kdesudo” (KDE).

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backintime
```

## [TimeShift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html):

> TimeShift for Linux is a application that provides functionality
>   similar to the System Restore feature in Windows and the Time Machine
>   tool in Mac OS. TimeShift protects your system by taking incremental
>   snapshots of the file system at regular intervals. These snapshots can
>   be restored later to bring your system to the exact state it was in at
>   the time when the snapshot was taken.
>
> TimeShift is designed to protect only system files and settings. User
>   files such as documents, pictures and music are excluded. This ensures
>   that your files remains unchanged when you restore your system to an
>   earlier date. If you need a tool to backup your documents and files
>   please take a look at the excellent [BackInTime](http://backintime.le-web.org/) application which
>   is more configurable and provides options for saving user files.
>
> Installation:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install timeshift
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hook for **apt** to run a *script* after each invocation of *apt-get/dpkg*.
A script that will list all installed package and commit the new list in a git repo

For example, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-dpkg-snapshot`

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/usr/bin/dpkg -l > /root/apt.git/dpkg-list.txt; git commit -a -m `date +%Y%m%d%H%H%S` -C /root/apt.git"; };
```

and create a **git** repo in `/root/apt.git`

But even with a list of package and their version, it could be not enough to get back a system in shape. You need at least to keep /etc with, for example etckeeper.

It would be better to use *snapshot* instead like @muru said. The problem is that only *btrfs* and *LVM* provide filesystem snapshot.

You could do it with device-mapper too but this is not trivial. https://serverfault.com/a/481513/297044

Comment: The problem with snapshots is mitigated somewhat since Ubuntu now uses LVM by default for new installations.